# Part of the model doesn't show vertices on it. Error message under Transform tab is "Nothing selected"

Tags: modeling

I'm super new to Blender and I don't know what I did wrong. I was modeling just now, and all of sudden I can't select any vertex on part of my model because there isn't any!
[image]

If I switch to edge mode or face mode, the non-affected part of the model behaves normally, but by selecting any edge or face of the problematic part of the model, no gizmo shows, and I see an error message of "Nothing selected" showing under the Transform tab, and I can't use any mesh tool on them. E.g. hit E and no gizmo is there.

[image][image]

FYI, I don't have any modifier on the mesh as you can see on the first screengrab. I could totally extrude faces and merge vertices just half an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything solves the problem.